# Visual Studio 2010 Professional: How to access Modules window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How do i access the **Modules** window in Visual Studio 2010?

---

**Irrelevant information**

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c8f14c9.aspx), only certain editions of Visual Studio let you access the modules window (i.e. Pro, Premium, Ultimate). i have Professional:

[image]

> **Note**: Strictly speaking i don't have **Pro**, but i assume **Pro** is shorthand for **Professional**

MSDN goes on to say:

> **To display the Modules window in break mode or in run mode**
>
> - On the Debug menu, choose Windows, and then click Modules.

Except i have no **Modules** menu option:

[image]

(*edit: updated screenshot to show debugging, sitting at a breakpoint*)

How do i access the **Modules** window in Visual Studio 2010?

---

### Irrelevant information

i tried to **Customize** the **Debug** -> **Windows** item:

[image]

except there is no **Debug** -> **Modules** item:

[image]

Nor is there any **Windows** -> **Modules** item:

[image]

How do i access the **Modules** window in Visual Studio 2010?

### See also

- MSDN: [How to: Use the Modules Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c8f14c9.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps you have to set a breakpoint and start running the app? There is no list of loaded modules for an app that hasn't loaded any. :)

Comment: @KenWhite Updated question with screenshot proof: Debugging, sitting at breakpoint.

Comment: Hmmm... Strange. That was the only diff I saw between your original screen cap and @Nacereddine's.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Possible solutions :

- Try the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> (Note that I configured my VS2010 for C# development the first time I started it so the shortcut may not be the same).
- Also, try repairing the install of VS2010 (This has helped me in the past).
- You can also reset VS settings from `Tools -> Import and Export settings -> Reset all settings`

Note that I also have VS2010 Professional edition and it's visible for me under `Debug -> Windows -> Modules` (I'm stopped at a break point here) :

[image]

**Edit :**

The option is also available in the Customize window

[image]

**P.S:** This option is only available when in **debug mode**

Comment: What happens if you try to customize the debug menu?

Comment: The option is also available there.

Comment: Dammit. Now if i can only get an explanation of why Visual Studio 2010 "Professional" doesn't have it. Are you running "Pro" or "Professional"?

Comment: @IanBoyd I am running "Visual Studio 2010 Professional" (Which I got from dreamspark.com, not that this changes anything, except for the price). There is only a Professional Edition, not Pro. They're all listed [here](https://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions)

Comment: `Ctrl+D, M` had no effect. i **Reset all settings** and now i have **Modules** window. Still begs the question how to customize Visual Studio to include Modules menu option. But someone else can ask that question, i've lost enough time on this. Losing all my keyboard shortcuts is an easy enough fix to call it answered.

Comment: @IanBoyd Next time, you can export only your keyboard settings to restore them after such drastic measures.

Comment: Too late! (It was only a dozen or so)

Answer (score 3):

From your screen shot of the Debug menu I can see that you are not running the application with the debugger attached (Press F5).  Most of the 'debug' windows (Threads, Watch, CallStack, Register, Modules) are not visible in the Debug Menu or the Visual Studio IDE unless you are debugging the application.

Are you at a breakpoint in your code before looking for the Modules window?

Comment: The last time i was able to run the project there still was no modules window. i've recursed four levels deep in Visual Studio and questions on stackoverflow about bugs in Visual Studio: `Scaling not working` -> `Framework debugging not working` -> `Modules window not working` -> `Settings not working in .NET 3.5`. Once i can get an answer to my nested *Settings crashing in .NET 3.5* i can `RET` to this question, updating the question with a screenshot proof. But i can tell you that there was no modules menu option at runtime.

Comment: Updated question with screenshot proof of no **Modules** menu option, while debugging, sitting at a breakpoint.

Comment: OK.  What type of project and what programming language?

Comment: I belive the settings for the Visual Studio debug menu are stored here. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VCSExpress\10.0\Debugger or HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Debugger

Comment: This was it for me in Visual Studio 2017 Community. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's Ctrl+Alt+u for launching Modules in C++ app development in VS.