# Debug .NET source code with VS2015 update1 in UWP / WPF / Console applications?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

Have tried these two，but they do not work :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source.aspx

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

// EDIT

some other information

**1, code:**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<string> s = new List<string>() {"1", "2", "3"};
            s.Sort();

        }
    }
```

**2, dumpbin /headers:**

Debug Directories

```
    Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
-------- ------- -------- -------- --------
570C5040 cv            25 004B34F0   4B16F0    Format: RSDS, {F0736C7E-9384-4F56-B409-82538DE2D731}, 2, mscorlib.pdb
```

**3, Modules window:**

    mscorlib.dll    C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll   Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\f0736c7e93844f56b40982538de2d7312\mscorlib.pdb 1   4.6.1080.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE 2016/4/12 9:32  728E0000-73A29000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll Yes N/A Cannot find or open the PDB file.       2   14.00.23107.0   2015/7/7 15:24  00CB0000-00CBE000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    System.Windows.Forms.dll    C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\System.Windows.Forms.pdb\eb5cb7959d814f46a194daf569c175ff1\System.Windows.Forms.pdb 3   4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2  2015/10/8 9:11  5D560000-5E1BA000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    System.dll  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll Yes N/A Cannot find or open the PDB file.       4   4.6.1081.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE 2016/4/19 5:29  71730000-720B8000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    System.Drawing.dll  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll Yes N/A Cannot find or open the PDB file.       5   4.6.1078.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE 2016/3/11 6:19  6E6C0000-6E84F000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll    C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll   Yes N/A Cannot find or open the PDB file.       6   14.00.23107.0   2015/7/7 15:24  00FA0000-00FAC000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll Yes N/A Symbols not loaded.     7   14.00.23107.0   2015/7/7 15:24  01010000-0101A000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe  C:\Users\HaoPeng\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe Yes N/A Cannot find or open the PDB file.       8   14.00.23107.0   2015/7/7 14:58  00BF0000-00BF8000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    System.Core.dll C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll   Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\System.Core.pdb\5005a16d6f1d4f578a8a839f7ec4e7342\System.Core.pdb    9   4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2  2015/10/8 9:11  69680000-69DA9000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    System.Xml.Linq.dll C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll   Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\System.Xml.Linq.pdb\b5b962082bfa460e9fce41fdc43a7a022\System.Xml.Linq.pdb    10  4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2  2015/10/8 9:11  59CE0000-59D42000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll   Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.pdb\ff8bd93350db450fb43f156c22d475e51\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.pdb    11  4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2  2015/10/8 9:10  05120000-05132000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    Microsoft.CSharp.dll    C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\Microsoft.CSharp.pdb\609aad548a5f4b1bafb09a5ccd9e8aa32\Microsoft.CSharp.pdb  12  4.06.1038.0 2015/10/8 9:11  54F60000-550E4000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    System.Data.dll C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\System.Data.pdb\ac876710b4974f1f984e433d02a293311\System.Data.pdb   13  4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2  2015/10/8 9:11  56340000-56ABD000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    System.Net.Http.dll C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll   Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\System.Net.Http.pdb\c43c636332fe4b53ad4e9f12dd1d68152\System.Net.Http.pdb    14  4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2  2015/10/8 9:10  668C0000-66941000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    System.Xml.dll  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\System.Xml.pdb\7f2700207ca5443a83d10b6e05ed34722\System.Xml.pdb  15  4.6.1064.2 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE 2015/12/3 9:36  66E30000-6753C000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    mscorlib.resources.dll  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_zh-Hans_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll  Yes N/A Binary was not built with debug information.        16  4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2  2015/10/8 12:05 05540000-05636000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    ConsoleApplication1.exe C:\Users\HaoPeng\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe    No  N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\HaoPeng\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pdb    17  1.00.0.0    2016/5/21 11:19 04FF0000-04FF8000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
    System.Configuration.dll    C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll Yes N/A Symbols loaded. C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\System.Configuration.pdb\870cb491dac3444aaa02db61d480a0e01\System.Configuration.pdb 18  4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2  2015/10/8 9:11  68720000-6880F000   [9384] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe   [1] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe

**4, symbol load info:**

```
C:\Users\HaoPeng\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\symbols\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\f0736c7e93844f56b40982538de2d7312\mscorlib.pdb: Symbols loaded.
```

// EDIT2
**Symbol load info**

```
C:\Users\HaoPeng\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\symbols\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\f0736c7e93844f56b40982538de2d7312\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\mscorlib.pdb\f0736c7e93844f56b40982538de2d7312\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
SYMSRV:  C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\F0736C7E93844F56B40982538DE2D7312\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


SYMSRV:  C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\F0736C7E93844F56B40982538DE2D7312\mscorlib.pdb not found


SYMSRV:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols/mscorlib.pdb/F0736C7E93844F56B40982538DE2D7312/mscorlib.pdb not found


http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server.
SYMSRV:  C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\F0736C7E93844F56B40982538DE2D7312\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


INFO:  HTTP_STATUS_OK


SYMSRV:  C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\F0736C7E93844F56B40982538DE2D7312\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


SYMSRV:  mscorlib.pdb from https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 133447 bytes 

https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols downloaded from symbol server.
C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\F0736C7E93844F56B40982538DE2D7312\mscorlib.pdb: Symbols loaded.
```

Comment: what does not work? Give more information (and error messages if you get them)

Comment: :)

`List<string> a = new List<string>() {"2", "1"};
 a.Sort();`
when I hit f11 at 'a.Sort();', VS2015 did not step into the source code of 'Sort' method. So, I mean it does not work.

Comment: have you uncheck **Just my code**? Also don't point to the public MS symbol server, they don't include source information.

Comment: :)  of course I unchecked **Just my code**, also I did not point to **Microsoft symbol server**, but when I run my app, VS2015 starts to download symbols from **Microsoft symbol server**, when it is finished, I still can not step into .Net source code. Maybe you can try it yourself.

Comment: Microsoft symbol server hosts public symbols and this is why it doesn't work. Have you configured the environment variable **_NT_SYMBOL_PATH** and configured here the MS Symbol server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27655501/17034

Comment: :(   does not work, thanks for providing me information.

Comment: It is the familiar problem I described in the linked Q+A.  You have the same version of mscorlib.dll on your machine as I do.  It got delivered through Windows Update on my machine on April 22nd.  This breaks the reference source, that server is not updated automatically from the build server like the msdl server is and it still has the old PDBs.  It can take a while before somebody wakes up and takes care of it.  You are stuck until that happens.

Comment: @HansPassant Hope MS could solve this.  :)

Comment: Hmya, SO is not the Microsoft Support email inbox.  You got the ear of a Microsoft employee who never heard of this problem, not exactly the most efficient way to go about it.  I'm closing this as dup, clearly it is.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** it looks like this is a problem on the Microsoft server side. The symbols for

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols/mscorlib.pdb/f0736c7e93844f56b40982538de2d7312/mscorlib.pdb

haven't been published yet. I'm confirming internally and will update here once the team responds.

---

This can happen when you first loaded public symbols (without source code mappings) from Microsoft Symbol Server, they got cached in the SymbolsCache folder, then you turned off public symbol server, however the old symbols still get picked up from the cache.

Try deleting this folder:
C:\Users\HaoPeng\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache
And try again.

Comment: I delete the folder and open the solution, then VS starts to Load symbols from: Microsoft Symbol Servers(a dialog shows up), when this is done, I click Start to run the demo, and VS starts to Downloading public symbols(another dialog shows up), when this is done,  I still can not step into .net source code.

Comment: Could you please delete the folder again, then paste the Symbol load info for mscorlib.dll?

Comment: :)   OK, I pasted the load info at 'EDIT2' above. Because it's too long to be a comment.

Comment: It looks like a problem on Microsoft side - symbols for f0736c... (NETFXREL3STAGE) haven't been published yet. Once I know more I will post more.

Comment: Also can you please make a screenshot of Visual Studio About dialog and paste here?

Comment: :) I do not have enough reputations to put more links here, so I put it on http://postimg.org/image/potvvhyup/   .