# Visual Studio steps over constructors and functions while debugging .NET Framework code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I wanted to step through and study MS implementation of data structures in `System.Collections.Generic`. Setted-up Visual Studio 2015 debugger to options you see below.

First issue: while trying to step into `LinkedList<int> list = new LinkedList<int>();` debugger steps over [`LinkedList`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,37) constructor. This particular constructor is empty. Is this a default behavior of VS debugger to step over empty constructors ?
Second issue: debugger steps over [`internal LinkedListNode(LinkedList<T> list, T value)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,614) constructor, instead of stepping in.
How do I force debugger to step into constructors ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The reference source symbol server is *very* slow to get updated.  You probably have .NET 4.6.2 on your machine right now, a version that it doesn't have yet.  You can only get a PDB from the msdl server but that one doesn't have source info.  You can see the debugger fail to get the PDB using [this procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27655501/17034).

Comment: @newprint, would you please share the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debug it in my side, it couldn't step into the LinkedList even if I use the correct debugging .NET framework source code steps [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2010/09/09/debugging-the-net-framework-source-code/), actually if I use the "Go To Definition" and visit the System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList, I also could step Into it even if I add a breakpoint firstly, so I think we couldn't step Into it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked here: [How to: Debug.Net Framework Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx)

Make sure you have the symbols loaded