# Symbols loaded, but still can't step into .Net source

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015, debug-symbols

I am trying to see the raw response message returned from a call to an internet-connected web API. The calling code looks like this:

```
object[] results = this.Invoke("MethodName", new object[] { requestObject });
```

The problem is that while debugging, the `results` variable already appears completely deserialized, for example the date property I'm interested in is already a `DateTime` type.

So I did the following:

1. Turned off "Enable Just My Code".
2. Turned on "Enable .Net Framework source stepping".
3. Enabled symbol loading and ensured that the System.Web.Services module has had symbols loaded ("Symbols loaded."):

   ```
   System.Web.Services.dll
   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll
   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\System.Web.Services.pdb\312122031d1b4f30b59771eb845018121\System.Web.Services.pdb
   ```
4. I dropped a breakpoint inside of the following method starting on line 163 of `SoapHttpClientProtocol.cs` (the one called by my client code):

   ```
   protected object[] Invoke(string methodName, object[] parameters)
   ```
5. I started debugging the project and used my UI to trigger the code that makes the request. When I get to the `Invoke` line above and press F11, it tries to remote debug and step into the remote server:

   > Microsoft Visual Studio
   >
   > Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine 'api.example.com' failed. The Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.

   Note: I have no desire to do remote debugging, I just want to step into the .Net code.

   After hitting OK, it goes to the next line in my client code without either stepping into the .Net library or hitting my breakpoint.
6. When I look at the breakpoint in break mode (instruction pointer still on line after the calling `Invoke` line), it is a hollow circle and says "This breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

   This makes no sense as the symbols have been loaded, as proven above.

How do I either step into the .Net source code, or perform this request via another means? This particular request is a bit more complicated than some, as it requires a certificate (.pfx file) as well as a username and password.

Hmmmmm... one data point is that the breakpoint I dropped is in a file which says at the top:

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
// Assembly: System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// MVID: A6D697F9-972E-41EC-820F-E59621A808B5
// Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Web.Services.dll
```

It suddenly seems to me that this is where the discrepancy may be coming from. Is JetBrains interfering with my stepping into .Net source?

Comment: Are you sure that specific source file is made available by Microsoft? Merely loading the symbols does not guarantee everything. If you doubt that JetBrains tools interfere, uninstall them and try again.

Comment: I turned off ReSharper and yes the file was decomposed by ReSharper. Microsoft only provides the method headers. I'm sure System.Web.Services is Microsoft though.

Comment: don't point to the default MS symbol server. use the reference server to get the private PDBs + src files: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: @magicandre1981 Okay, so I've followed [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html) but no improvement yet.

Comment: have you deleted the symbol cache, otherwise VS doesn't fetch the new PDBs?

Comment: @ ErikE, what about this issue? Would you please share the latest information for this issue? :)

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I will follow up tomorrow!

Comment: @ ErikE, I look forward to hearing from you:)

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I'm very sick today. Soonish.

Answer (score 7):

> > Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine 'api.example.com' failed. The Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer.

So actually you just debug your web app locally, but you got the remote debugging error/warning, am I right?

Like this document here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164726.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> If you are getting this message while you are debugging locally, your anti-virus software or a third-party firewall may be to blame. Visual Studio is a 32-bit application, so it uses the 64-bit version of the remote debugger to debug 64-bit applications. The two processes communicate using the local network within the local computer. No traffic leaves the computer, but it is possible that third party security software may block the communication.

In addition, you use the correct steps to debug the .NET Framework source code after your discussions:

[image]

But if you use the VS2015, you need to think about that whether the Reference source has been updated for the .NET framework:

[Cannot step into .NET framework source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655014/cannot-step-into-net-framework-source-code)

A user voice here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6886255-please-keep-the-reference-source-symbol-server-upd