# Debugging: Trouble stepping into external source code (nuget)

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

**Problem**
Attempting to debug why my configuration isn't binding to my object the way I want it to and I can't seem to step into ConfigurationRoot.Get();. It either breaks inside the method or steps over when I try to step into it.

I believe my debugger settings are correct and I've verified the correct modules and symbols are loaded as well. Any suggestions on what to check for next?

*Running Visual Studio 2017*

Relevant Packages:

- *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (1.1.1)*
- *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder (1.1.1)*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe I should also mention that I'm running dotPeek symbol server with VS configured to use it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using information from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693502/how-do-i-debug-net-4-6-framework-source-code-in-visual-studio-2017?rq=1), I deleted the symbols for the *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration** from my symbol cache. I then double checked my debug settings and discovered that they had been reset to default somehow. After choosing the correct settings again, deleting the symbols from cache, and only enabling dotPeek as my symbol server, VS was able to load the PDB files and then step into the source as I wanted.

[image]