# Stepping into .NET Source Still Doesn't Work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

This is embarrassing -- I've been programming .NET for many years and despite [following the MSDN instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source) for debugging the .NET sources, I've never been able to get it to work.

When I attempt to step into some Framework code (the c'tor for `StringBuilder`, for example), the debugger just skips right over, onto the next statement. I can't step into *any* framework code.

I'm using VS 2017, Framework v4.7.

Below are the debugging options.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Microsoft fails to always provide latest symbol files for all .NET Framework releases, so what you experienced is normal. Anyway the source code is just for reference purposes, and if you do meet critical product issues, you should open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: @Lex - I think what you said cannot be correct. I just dropped down to Framework v4 and I have the same problem.  What do you mean the source code is just for "reference purposes"? No it's not -- it's for debugging and stepping into.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot step into .NET framework source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655014/cannot-step-into-net-framework-source-code)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Symbols and add this URL http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols and a local cache path.

Please see:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sburke/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code/

Other community members asked the simliar issue about debugging the .NET 4.6 here:

[How do I debug .NET 4.6 framework source code in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693502/how-do-i-debug-net-4-6-framework-source-code-in-visual-studio-2017)

Update:

It really has this issue from old VS version to VS2017, anyway, since we could repro this issue now, if possible, like Leo's suggestion, you could vote and add your comment here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/101533/could-not-debug-net-framework-on-windws-10-machine.html

Comment: The "search only when symbols are loaded manually" option does not seem to be available or has been moved somewhere as it is not showing up on the window.

Comment: @JasonH, it was an option in old VS version, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: is there not something similar in VS2017?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, Microsoft seems to have abandoned this feature. No wonder Apple is eating your lunch. The link you sent me was from 2008, and it didn't work.The link I originally posted is from 2016, which didn't work. The instructions at "http://referencesource.microsoft.com" have a link for configuring VS 2013 (an old version) and those instructions don't work either. See a pattern?

This feature has been around a long time now. I got it to work once a few years ago but never again. This stuff should be seamless by now. It should be easy.

Comment: @TomBaxter, According to the second link that Jack provided, I configure my VS2017 with below steps and it works. And based on your screenshot, please also checked all sub-options of “Enable source server support” and checked “Require source files to exactly match the original version” option in VS Options -> Debugging -> General.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT I updated the my config as you described but I get the exact same result -- skipping over framework code. Are you using Framework 4.7? I have the Modules window open when I debug and the .pdb files are loaded successfully (for System.dll and mscorlib.dll). In the Modules window, under the "Version" column it reads this: "4.7.2531.0 built by: NET471REL1". In the Output window it reads this: "Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded."

Comment: @TomBaxter, I have tested this issue with my colleague. We found this problem occurs on Windows 10 machine. It could debug on Windows 7 machine with above Visual Studio settings. We have submit this issue to Visual Studio Developer Community. You could vote it from this link:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/101533/could-not-debug-net-framework-on-windws-10-machine.html

Comment: @Leo-MSFT - THANK YOU!

Comment: @TomBaxter, I just edit my previous answer, since leo help you report this issue to the product team, you could vote and add your comment there. The product team would share the update if they get any useful information.