# First time exception - System.pdb not loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I use VS2017 and I get the following when I hit F5

[image]

It happens for certain projects only, even if I disabled the Symbols support under VS options. Although in the past, for the same projects it used not to throw even with Symbol support enabled.

So, since I assumed this must be some kind of cached VS setting project specific, I deleted bin, obj, .vs , SymbolSource folders but the same.

If I enable Just My Code it does not throw, however this is not what I want since I cannot debug assemblies which I already have the symbols.

As far as I know even if Symbols Support is enabled it shouldn't throw if there isn't a related Symbol Server declared in VS Options.

This behavior is not specific only to System.dll but happens even if I attach to external processes which I do not have symbols, meaning that filtering with the Load Only Specified Module VS option again is not what I am looking for.

So, does anybody have an idea on how to avoid such annoying exceptions while allowing to utilize Symbol Support for other assemblies which I have configured.

Comment: I want to break but only if I have symbols as it used to break in the past. I try to understand why now it breaks on assemblies that I do not have symbols

Answer (score 11):

It means that you want to step in to the 
.net Framework source code:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/indexedpdbs.txt

Actually we also reported this issue to product team for VS 2017 before:

[Stepping into .NET Source Still Doesn't Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828032/stepping-into-net-source-still-doesnt-work)

If you really want to avoid it, I suggest you disable settings like "Enable .NET framework source stepping" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging.

To debug .NET framework source code,we need to:

> Disable just my code
>
> Disable step over properties and operators
>
> Disable require source files to exactly match the original version
>
> Enable .NET framework source stepping
>
> Enable source server support

So just use the contrary settings as above options, debug it again.

In addition, please enable the symbols server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols Server, and enable the exception settings window, view the detailed exception messages, maybe you have to resolve the Exception firstly or get any helpful information from it.

Comment: >If you really want to avoid it, I suggest you disable settings like "Enable .NET framework source stepping" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging.

It is disabled already but still throowing

Comment: @Apostolis Bekiaris, just add other suggestions for this issue, if possible, you could view it in above answer. If still no help, could you share a simple sample using one drive? So we could debug it in our side using the same sample as yours.

Answer (score 3):

I had to check **Enable native code debugging** under **Debug** tab in project properties window (Refer screenshot). After that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save the property window changes.

Thus after saving project properties, issues goes away whenever we start a new debugging session.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me because I was using external DLL which didn't have the PDB file with it. I found that when I removed all the breakpoints.

Go to Debug menu > Windows > Exception Settings (or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>)

Now check **Common Language Runtime Exceptions** or click <kbd>Restore default</kbd> (Refer screenshot):

[image]

So when it throws exception and you don't see it, it want to use the PDB file to store the stack trace but it didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to uncheck the debug hosting service.

[image: This worked for me!]