# How to step inside/debugging the code source of web.api 2 and System.Web dll

Tags: asp.net, debugging, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-debugging

I wanted to step inside/debugging the web-api 2 (version 5.2.3) code source to understand it.

I've created a simple web api application, and in the **WebApi.config**, I've set a break point at this line:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ExcludedRoute",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
           constraints: new { Controller = "healthcheck", action = "check" }
       );
```

I could step inside the MapHttpRoute method and the other classes, but the debugger couldn't step inside the Route class from the **System.Web** dll, below the image:

[image]

I tried to use this symbol file locations:
[image]

I've also used the dotpeek tool for generating the pdb files from the bin folder, by setting to true the "copy local" feature  of the referenced assemblies, but with no success. The path of system.web dll is

***C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.dll***

I'm wondering Why the debugger couldn't step inside the Route class which belongs to the system.Web dll, its version is 4.0 and the version of web.api is the 5.2.3.

In my searching, I've downloaded the code source of the asp.net and i found that the project System.Web.Http.WebHost which contains the HttpWebRoute class.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assembly System.Web.pdb was in the .NET Framework source code. You need to configure Visual Studio for debugging .NET framework in the Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General menu.

Reference:

[How do I debug .NET 4.6 framework source code in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693502/how-do-i-debug-net-4-6-framework-source-code-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, i've configured visual studio with the standard source servers, but the result was not good. I've prefered to use the dotpeek tool to generate the pdb files, but even with that, the system.web.pdb didn't allow me to step inside the route class.

Comment: @Issa Dawaji, So you set the correct settings like this document:https://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html, am I right? If so, do you get any warning or error messages during you debug your app?