# Allow Microsoft symbol server through firewall

Tags: visual-studio, debug-symbols, symbol-server

We have a new setup where we don't have internet access for our machines which we code on. (Stupid Idea in my opinion). Our Network Security department wants to know if the following URL is the only URL needed to allow firewall access to Microsoft's Symbol server.

msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Is this the same URL that visual studio uses when it goes off and tries to download the needed `.pdb` files when debugging?

Comment: There is no single correct answer.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27655501/17034) shows how you find out when you get in trouble, note that it lists more than one symbol server.

Comment: @HansPassant That post deals with getting `.pdb` files with a newer framework. At the time of the post it looks like `.NET 4.5.2` was the latest. We currently develop on `.NET 4.5.2` so I don't think that post's issue would be a problem.

Comment: Nothing to do with the framework version, the point was to help you see how you diagnose symbol server problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to that url you will see you get an HTTP 302 response, which redirect you to another URL depending on what symbol you request for. I hope your firewall supports pattern matching for URLs.
Here is a non exhaustive list i got from my windows server 2016 c++ project

```
vsblobprodscussu5shard1.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard3.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard10.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard11.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard13.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard14.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard18.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard19.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard20.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard21.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard24.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard32.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard37.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard38.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard56.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard65.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard80.blob.core.windows.net
vsblobprodscussu5shard81.blob.core.windows.net
```