# How to debugging .Net Framework (4.8) source code on Windows 10

Tags: .net, debugging

I want to go into the `SetAuthCookie`.

### Describe

Windows 10 21H1

Visual Studio 2019 16.11.7

- Disable just my code
- Disable step over properties and operators
- Disable require source files to exactly match the original version
- Enable .NET framework source stepping
- Enable source server support

```cs
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(username.Text == "admin" && password.Text == "123")
            {
// Breakpoint
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username.Text, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Pushing <kbd>F11</kbd> causes the debugger to simply skip to the next line.

Open modules window, `System.Web.dll` version is `4.8.4330.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B`.

Uninstall windows update show alert:

> Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4601554) is required by your computer and cannot be uninstalled.

### See Also

[How do you enable "Enable .NET Framework source stepping"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139269/how-do-you-enable-enable-net-framework-source-stepping)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you switch to ASP.Net Core instead of the .net framework? The souce for that is always available.

Answer (score 0):

Using dotPeek as the symbol server worked for me. (4.6.2 framework) (I did everything mentioned in other threads and nothing worked)

https://hmemcpy.com/2014/07/how-to-debug-anything-with-visual-studio-and-jetbrains-dotpeek-v1-2/

JetBrains dotPeek decompiles your actual .NET DLLs, then hosts a symbol server that you download symbols from in Visual Studio.
After a pretty slow download, then a restart of VS, I was able to breakpoint and step into the code.